# Photoshop parameters: Design for Android

Tags: android, photoshop

I am beginning with the designs of my android application in Photoshop. I though I had to begin with the perfect support for medium density on a normal screen. So I would go to HVGA(320x480). Is this the right table to support most of the screensize? and is this the right parameter to design in photoshop for HVGA(320x480)?

[image: parameters]

[image: screensizes]

Answer (score 0):

> Graphic designers aren't programmers and sometimes don't know how to
>   properly prepare graphic assets for developers. This simple cheatsheet
>   should help them to do their job better, and to simplify developers'
>   lives.

Must Visit **[Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/)**

Comment: Thanks for the usefull link. But i like to make a background image is the right format. Before I receive a background image with a resolution from 1300x2000px wich gave me by loading 3 activities a outofmemory error.